# Java: Convert Primitive Class

Tags: java, reflection, class, casting

is there an easy in Java to convert primitive class objects into object class objects? Given a class Class cl, I want to convert it into a Class that has no primitives. Eg.

```
Class<?> cl = int.class;

...
if (cl.isPrimitive()) {
  cl = Object of primitive
}
...
```

cl == Integer.class

I would like a method that does that for all primitive types. Obviously I could iterate through all primitive types, but I thought someone may know about a better solution.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Just create a map constant. I don't think eight cases are worth bothering.

Comment: Yeah... you're right. Already did that anyway, just thought I might miss a method that does that for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hope I understood it right. Basically you want a mapping from primitive class types to their wrapper methods.

A static utility method implemented in some Utility class would be an elegant solution, because you would use the conversion like this:

```
Class<?> wrapper = convertToWrapper(int.class);
```

Alternatively, declare and populate a static map:

```
public final static Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
static {
    map.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
    map.put(byte.class, Byte.class);
    map.put(short.class, Short.class);
    map.put(char.class, Character.class);
    map.put(int.class, Integer.class);
    map.put(long.class, Long.class);
    map.put(float.class, Float.class);
    map.put(double.class, Double.class);
}

private Class<?> clazz = map.get(int.class);  // usage
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how I ended up doing it. Thanks for that.

Comment: you forgot void.class.   just sayin'

Comment: _or_ [slightly better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62219759/1059372)

Answer (score 13):

org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(Class)

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, if you're using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it has [Primitives class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html), which you can use like this:

```
Primitives.wrap(int.class); //returns Class<Integer>
Primitives.wrap(Integer.class); //returns Class<Integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Guava and Apache Commons use an underlying `HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>` which isn't really necessary, but makes for readible code.

- Commons Lang3 implementation: [org.apache.commons.lang.ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-lang.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ClassUtils.java;h=0a7480ff8d991e555be679f86377dc19d3eb64d7;hb=HEAD#l78)
- Guava implementation: [com.google.common.primitives.Primitives.wrap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.java#36)

The following über-optimized snippet performs the same functionality in constant time, as it maps to a Wrapper class via an index lookup:

```
private static final Class[] wrappers = {
        Integer.class,
        Double.class,
        Byte.class,
        Boolean.class,
        Character.class,
        Void.class,
        Short.class,
        Float.class,
        Long.class
};

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Class<T> wrap(final Class<T> clazz) {
    if (!clazz.isPrimitive()) return clazz;
    final String name = clazz.getName();
    final int c0 = name.charAt(0);
    final int c2 = name.charAt(2);
    final int mapper = (c0 + c0 + c0 + 5) & (118 - c2);
    return (Class<T>) wrappers[mapper];
}
```

There is a bit of code golf involved, so don't reorder the classes unless you know what you're doing ;)

Comment: Can you explain the essence of how the algorithm works?

Comment: It uses two letters of the actual classnames in order to perform a very constrained index lookup. The same algorithm will work for converting wrappers into primitives as well, the only difference is that you need to lookup letters 10 and 12 instead (java.lang. prefix).

Here is some more code, along side with unit tests:
https://github.com/melezov/runtime-bytegen/blob/master/src/main/java/org/revenj/Primitives.java