# Finding reference class given primitive class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to build a more-typesafe alternative to base Java reflection, and have run up against a bit of a problem.  I've got a class `BoundMethod<T>` that binds a method and an object so the method can be invoked and the result (of type T) returned in a typesafe manner.  This involves passing a Class to the constructor, and using that class to cast the return value (i.e. `return returnType.cast(method.invoke(object, params))`).

The problem I have is that if I create these objects automatically based on the results of `getReturnType()` in the method object and the return type is a primitive object, I get a ClassCastException, because you can't dynamically cast to a primitive type.  I need a way of substituting the appropriate reference type, but I can't find an easy way of doing this.

Is there some prebuilt solution, or do I need to build one myself?

Comment: You have to map all the primitive types to their wrappers. e.g. with a `Map<Class, Class>` The Refection Library only uses wrappers in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `returnType` and see if it is a primitive:

```
returnType.isPrimitive();
```

And if it is, [get its wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704634/simple-way-to-get-wrapper-class-type-in-java).

Unfortunately, this opens you up to auto-boxing of values, but that's simply what happens when you mix generics and primitives.