# Default value from a class

Tags: java

How do I write a function which returns a default value for the given class? If a class is one of the primitives it should return a wrapper class with default value, else return null.

```java
public <B> Object defaultValue(Class<B> clazz) {
    return clazz.isPrimitive() ? ... : null;
}
```

So for `int.class` it should return `Integer(0)`.

Comment: You can't do it in a single line (if that's what you wanted to do).

Comment: Doesn't have to be a single line.

Comment: Make separate 'if' cases for each of the possible classes.

Comment: Then use a long list of `if/else` statements.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704634/simple-way-to-get-wrapper-class-type-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I write a function which returns a default value for the given class? If a class is one of the primitives it should return a wrapper class with default value, else return null.

So I assume that for primitives like `int.class` you want to return `new Integer(0)`, but for lets say Objects you want to return `null`.

If that is true you can use fact that arrays are filled with default values at start. Try maybe this way

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
...

public static <B> Object defaultValue(Class<B> clazz) {
    return Array.get(Array.newInstance(clazz, 1),0);
}
```

- `Array.newInstance(clazz, 1)` will create array of type `clazz` with one default element,
- `Array.get(<someArray>, 0)` will return its first element.
- also since your method `defaultValue` returns Object it will be autoboxed to corresponding type `int`->`Integer`.

---

Example

```
System.out.println(defaultValue(int.class));
System.out.println(defaultValue(int.class).getClass());
```

prints

```
0
class java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieve it is using a map to store the values:

```
private static Map<Class, Object> defaultValues = new HashMap<Class, Object>();

static {
    defaultValues.put(byte.class, 0);
    defaultValues.put(short.class, 0);
    defaultValues.put(int.class, 0);
    defaultValues.put(long.class, 0L);
    defaultValues.put(float.class, 0.0f);
    defaultValues.put(double.class, 0.0d);
    defaultValues.put(char.class, '\u0000');
    defaultValues.put(boolean.class, false);
}

public <B> Object defaultValue(Class<B> clazz) {
    return defaultValues.containsKey(clazz) ? defaultValues.get(clazz) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ClassUtils` class of the [Apache lang3 library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ClassUtils;

public Object defaultValue(Class<?> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
        IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    final Class<?> c = ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(clazz);
    if (c != null && !c.equals(clazz)) {
        final Constructor[] ctors = c.getConstructors();
        Constructor ctor = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ctors.length; i++) {
            ctor = ctors[i];
            if (ctor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0)
            break;
        }
        return ctor.newInstance(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It returns a null if the given class is not a primitive. You might want to handle the exception in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this? Defaulting is done by the compiler, not by calling existing methods.

Here are the default values for primitives, you could certainly write a function that turns this table into values...

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
Object      null
boolean     false
```

[Read this tutorial link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)