# Caling getter methods on an Object using reflection which includes all composite object's getters as well

Tags: java, reflection, comparison, getter

I want to validate all properties in an object A (say a). Class A has composite object B which has its own properties.

Class A

```
public Class A {

      private String name;

      private B b;

      private Set<SomeObject> fields = new HashSet<SomeObject>();

      //getter and setters for name and b

}
```

Class B

```
public Class B {

      private String address;

      private String dob;

      //getter and setters for address and dob

}
```

-----EDIT ----- 
Class SomeObject

```
public Class SomeObject{

        private Double amount;

        //getter and setters for amount
}
```

Logic to get value **name** and object **b** using reflection

```
    Field[] fields = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    for (Field field : fields) {

        String fieldName = field.getName();
        System.out.println(" *** Field Name *** "   + fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object obj1 = field.get(a);
        System.out.println(" *** Object 1 *** " + obj1);
    }
```

--EDIT ---

I use reflection to get value of **name** dynamically. But how do I know there is property B which is a composite object or a Set of another object and I should apply reflection on B to get values of **address** and **dob**. Again how can I get values from Set and apply reflection on iteration. Is there a better solution without iteration.

Other way round, I should determine if a class is Wrapper class (String, Integer etc) or User defined class(User Defined Bean). If wrapper class/primitive then no getter invocation. Again If it is collection or something I should iterate and apply reflection on each Object to get **amount**

Is there any java API available which can do this level of data extraction from a complex object. eg EquiBuilder, BeanUtils etc

Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Field.getType().isPrimitive()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isPrimitive%28%29) to find out if a field is of a primitive type (int, bool, &c.). If it's not, you have some object type, and if the field's value is not `null` you should recursively traverse the referenced object's fields.

It seems there's no built-in way of discriminating between primitive wrappers and other Java classes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704658/1015327 has a suggestion for a work-around, manually gathering the primitive wrapper classes.

Comment: By the time it reaches validator layer, both Wrapper and User defined class type object will be not null. It would have instantiated/ populated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple or straightforward way to do what you want. There is a large number of possible field types. The field can be primitive, `Collection`, costume type, `Date`, `UUID`, `JLabel`, etc.

If you know the set of possible built-in types that you'll encounter, you might be able to hack your way through it. First get the type of the field, and then run the type through a series of checks against the possible types. If a match is found, cast and retrieve the value(s). If no match is found, then you can assume that this is a custom type with its own fields.

You still have to worry about custom types that extends built-in types (e.g. custom `Map`). Honestly, I don't think reflection is the way to go here.

Comment: May be I could put the question in better way. A class can have not only Wrapper Classes like Integer or String etc but it can have any other Java provided classes like Set<>, List<>, Date etc. I am editing the question.