# How to judge boolean equals to Boolean or long equals to Long in java?

Tags: java, reflection, return-type

I hava two methods, one is `boolean getA()`, another one is `void setA(Boolean a)`.
I need judge the get method return type is equal to set method param type to do something.

```
// set method param type
Class<?> paramType = m2.getParameterTypes()[0];
// get method return type
Class<?> returnType = m1.getReturnType();
```

How can I judge these two type equal?

Comment: Well, the two types aren't equal, so it's not clear what you want to do. Do you mean that you want to test whether the primitive can be boxed into the non-primitive class? Possibly relevant threads: [Simple way to get wrapper class type in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704634/535871) and [Dynamically find the class that represents a primitive Java type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/180097/535871)

Comment: You can pass them through Guava's [`Primitives.wrap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#wrap(java.lang.Class)) or [`Primitives.unwrap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)) before comparing them.

Comment: @shmosel thanks a lot. You solved my big problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types are not equal.  `boolean` and `Boolean` are different types.

So if you want to *treat* them as equal in some (reflective) context, then the logic of your application has to deal with that.

For the record:

- The runtime representation of the type `boolean` can be obtained via `Boolean.TYPE` or `boolean.class`.
- The runtime representation of the type `Boolean` can be obtained via `Boolean.TRUE.getClass()` or `Boolean.class`.  Note the differences in case!
- If you lookup a method or constructor reflectively, then you need to provide the correct argument type.  The reflection APIs (generally) do not understand the JLS rules for disambiguating overloaded methods.
- When you use `Method.invoke`, you need to pass a `boolean` argument wrapped as a `Boolean`.

The above apply to all primitive types and their respective wrapper types.

Answer (score 0):

To *judge* if the types are equal, call `equals()`:

```
if (returnType.equals(paramType)) {
    // Same type
} else {
    // Different type
}
```

In your example, the `else` clause will execute, because `boolean` and `Boolean` are not the same type, i.e. [`Boolean.class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) is not equal to [`Boolean.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#TYPE) (the `Class` object representing the *primitive type* `boolean`).

Answer (score -1):

You mean convert boolean primitive to Boolean object, don't you?
To convert primitive to Object:

```
boolean bPrimitive = true;
Boolean bObject = Boolean.valueOf(bPrimitive);
```

To convert Object to primitive:

```
bPrimitive = bObject.booleanValue();
```

Hope this help.