# Primitive type classes (java)

Tags: java

I would like to get an Array of Classes corresponding to the classes of an Array of Objects. I wrote this code:

```
Object[] parameters = new Object[]{...};

Class[] classes = new Class[parameters.length];
for(int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++){
  classes[i] = parameters[i].getClass();
}
```

However, I need primitive types such as int or float writen as *float.class* or *int.class*
would do, but I instead get *java.lang.Float* or *java.lang.Integrer*. Is there anything I could do?

Comment: Not really, but thanks. I do actually need this for reflection.

Comment: The values in an `Object[]` can never be primitive types. Only `Float`/`Integer`/... can occur, there's no way you can get a `float`/`int`/ ... here.

Comment: @Progman: they expect `int.class` to be returned by `parameters[i].getClass()` (where `parameters` is an `Object[]`). That can obviously never happen, as an `Object[]` can not hold primitive values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Object[]` can never contain a primitive type directly. It can only contain the wrapper types `Integer`/`Float`/...

This is the reason why `classes[i]` in your code will never contain `int.class`.

Note that an `Object[]` *can* contain an `int[]` which in turn can contain `int` values (and only `int` values), but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: And is there any way to get the primitive type form the wrapper type?

Comment: @xImperiak: unfortunately there's no sweet one-line solution that'll give you that in the JDK, which is why [many utility libraries have such a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704634/simple-way-to-get-wrapper-class-type-in-java).